# Having errors while inserting values to mysql

Tags: java, mysql

When i insert value to mysql, there is data trancation and state that Data too long for column 'foodName' at row 1. Is there ways that i can solve this issue ?

Comment: Data which you have provided for foodName is too long for column 'foodName'

Comment: @OP: It is like trying to insert 10 chars in a column which can accommodate only 6 chars. Check your `foodName` column definition.

Answer (score 2):

You need to adjust the size of the column you are trying to add data too. Since it's foodName I'll just presume its a VARCHAR and you should see the length of that if you view the structure of the table VARCHAR (XXX).

You either need to do:

ALTER TABLE **table_name** MODIFY **col_name** VARCHAR(**length**);

OR

Make sure you are imposing a maximum length on the data that can be inserted into the foodName column which corresponds to the size of the column in MySQL.

Good luck!

Comment: This has more info on varchar http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/char.html
Or you may want to look at larger data types, ie text
http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/string-types.html